# ILISP installation troubles

Tags: emacs, lisp

OK I am aware that ILISP is no longer developed, but SLIME does not have some of the features of ILISP, ie autocompletion, highlighting user-defined functions, argument list hints for user functions, etc

I found a newer repository for ILISP package at [this place](https://github.com/barak/ilisp). I am using SBCL on linux.
I had to edit `ilcompat.el` and add

```
   ((string-match "^24" emacs-version)
         'fsf-23)
```

to make it compile with Emacs 24.x. it does compile with a *huge amount* of warnings.
Then as per `INSTALLATION` doc, I added `(load "ilisp/ilisp.emacs")` into my `~/.emacs` file.;

But upon emacs startup, i get an error. I dont know emacs enough to fix this??

```
Loading 00debian-vars...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50cmake-data.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50devhelp.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Loading debian-ispell...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...done
Loading debian-ispell...done
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50gcl.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50ilisp.el (source)...
Loading /etc/ilisp/ilisp.el (source)...
Loading /etc/ilisp/ilisp-keybindings.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/ilisp/ilisp.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50ilisp.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50slime.el (source)...
Loading /usr/share/emacs24/site-lisp/slime/slime-autoloads.elc...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50slime.el (source)...done
Loading /home/robin/.emacs.d/paredit.el (source)...done
Loading /home/robin/ilisp-master/ilisp.emacs...
Loading ilfsf23...done
Loading /home/robin/ilisp-master/ilisp.emacs...done
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
Loading ilcompat...
Loading ilfsf23...done
Loading ilcompat...done
Loading comint-ipc...done
Loading extra/cltl2...done
Loading ilisp-def...done
Loading ilisp-sym...done
Loading ilisp-inp...done
Loading ilisp-ind...done
Loading ilisp-prc...done
Loading ilisp-val...done
Loading ilisp-out...done
Loading ilisp-mov...done
Loading ilisp-key...done
Loading ilisp-prn...done
Loading ilisp-low...done
Loading ilisp-doc...done
Loading ilisp-ext...done
Loading ilisp-mod...done
Loading ilisp-dia...done
Loading ilisp-cmt...done
Loading ilisp-rng...done
Loading ilisp-hnd...done
Loading ilisp-utl...done
Loading ilisp-cmp...done
Loading ilisp-kil...done
Loading ilisp-snd...done
Loading ilisp-xfr...done
Loading ilisp-hi...done
Loading ilisp-aut...done
Loading /home/robin/ilisp-master/ilisp-cl.el (source)...
File mode specification error: (invalid-function (\` (progn (defvar ((\, hook)) nil ((\, (format "*Inferior %s hook." full-name)))) (defvar ((\, program)) nil ((\, (format "*Inferior %s default program." full-name)))) (defun ((\, setup)) (buffer) ((\, (format "Set up for interacting with %s." full-name))) ((\, (read (format "(setup-%s buffer)" parent)))) ((\,@ body)) (setq ilisp-program (or ((\, program)) ilisp-program) ilisp-dialect (cons (quote ((\, dialect))) ilisp-dialect)) (run-hooks (quote ((\, (read (format "%s-hook" dialect))))))) (defun ((\, dialect)) (&optional buffer program) ((\, (format "Create an inferior %s.  With prefix, prompt for buffer and program." full-name))) (interactive (list nil nil)) (ilisp-start-dialect (or buffer ((\, dialects))) program (quote ((\, setup)))) (setq ((\, program)) ilisp-program)) (lisp-add-dialect ((\, dialects))))))
Loading vc-git...done
byte-code: Beginning of buffer [4 times]
```

Comment: SLIME does not have what? Are you sure you have read the SLIME manual? http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/

Comment: @Rainer M-tab doesnt pick up user defined functions. And suggestions do not show up inline but in separate buffer.

Comment: What does it mean it 'doesn't pick up user defined functions'? Sure it finds user defined functions for completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that ILISP uses outdated backquote syntax.  The error seems to come from [the definition of defdialect in ilisp-dia.el](https://github.com/barak/ilisp/blob/9dde83ede6febe0170f95c90b137f2cdad68f554/ilisp-dia.el#L110):

```
(defmacro defdialect (dialect full-name parent &rest body)
  "Define a new ILISP dialect.
DIALECT is the name of the function to invoke the inferior LISP. The
hook for that LISP will be called DIALECT-hook.  The default program
will be DIALECT-program.  FULL-NAME is a string that describes the
inferior LISP.  PARENT is the name of the parent dialect."

  (let ((setup (read (format "setup-%s" dialect)))
        (hook (read (format "%s-hook" dialect)))
        (program (read (format "%s-program" dialect)))
        (dialects (format "%s" dialect)))
    (`
     (progn
       (defvar (, hook) nil (, (format "*Inferior %s hook." full-name)))
...
```

The function-like usage of backquote and comma is deprecated in Emacs Lisp. From the NEWS file for Emacs 24.1:

> ** Support for "old-style" backquotes, obsolete for 10+ years, has
>   been further reduced.  Now a backquote not followed by a space is
>   always treated as a "new-style" backquote.  Please remove all
>   "old-style" backquotes from your code.  If your code uses backquotes
>   as documented in the Elisp manual, and compiles without warning, then
>   you have nothing to do in this regard.  Code not following the
>   appropriate conventions may fail to compile.
>
> The most common cause of trouble seems to be an old-style backquote
>   followed by a newline.

So this code should be rewritten to something like:

```
(defmacro defdialect (dialect full-name parent &rest body)
  (let ((setup (read (format "setup-%s" dialect)))
        (hook (read (format "%s-hook" dialect)))
        (program (read (format "%s-program" dialect)))
        (dialects (format "%s" dialect)))
    `(progn
       (defvar ,hook nil ,(format "*Inferior %s hook." full-name))
...
```

(Though I suspect it would be a better use of time to get SLIME running properly.)